# Change [payu] to [payubiz]

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-wiki

According to [this article](http://www.nextbigwhat.com/payu-rebranding-297/), PayU India fully separated its PayU Enterprise and PayUmoney products earlier this year and renamed PayU Enterprise to PayUbiz.

- [payu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/payu) has 48 questions and a brief tag wiki, most of which is naming the countries that it's available in
- [payumoney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/payumoney) has 12 questions and a tag wiki that is clearly an advertisement
- 5 questions have both tags

**I suggest that we change [payu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/payu) to [payubiz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/payubiz) and rewrite the tag wikis for it and [payumoney](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/payumoney).** (I would rewrite them myself, but I think someone with more knowledge of these products should do it.)

Comment: Good luck finding a knowledgeable person here on SO. From the Tag Wiki's stats page: `All Time 83.3% unanswered `. And the tag wiki for [tag:payumoney] is a bit spammy.